I want to execute a Go script within Flutter. Is there any possible way to do this?
I want to execute a Go script within Flutter. Is there any possible way to do this and send data to a BMS device? Can I achieve this with Flutter?
"Can I use MethodChannels to execute the Go script? Will it work?
Otherwise I'll havhe to implement the whole script into dart.
